# android OkHttp clear disk cache image entry

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

Just like picasso has Picasso.with(context).invalidate(url) , 
Does okhttp have any mechanism for clearing a disk cache entry given a key?

Answer (score 3):

As the user polbins stated [here](https://gist.github.com/polbins/1c7f9303d2b7d169a3b1) this seems like can be achieved like this.

```
public static void removeFromCache(String urlString) {
    try {
        Iterator<String> it = mCache.urls();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String next = it.next();

            if (next.contains(urlString)) {
                it.remove();
            }   
        }   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

mCache instance is the cache instance that you set to OkHttpClient, like this.

```
Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setCache(cache);
```

Comment: unbelievable , so common functionality so 'good' accessible... A was trying to replace androidquery but this I was missing...